# ¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra "albañil"?

Tags: etimología

La palabra *albañil* parece similar a Albania, el país. ¿Es posible que ambas palabras estén relacionadas etimológicamente?

La [definición en el DLE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1V5zVWR) no dice nada sobre el origen de la palabra.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En [Etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?alban.il) encontramos:

> Al igual que muchas palabras que empieza por al-, la palabra albañil viene del árabe, al-banní­, pronunciación dialectal andalusí del árabe clásico البنّاء (al-bannāˀ) "el constructor" y este del verbo بنى (banā) "construir".

Answer (score 8):

No están relacionadas, porque *albañil* viene del árabe *al banna* ("el constructor"), mientras que *Albania* viene del latín, probablemente desde la raíz *albus* ("blanco") con el significado de "tierras blancas", o desde la palabra *albanii* (el nombre de una hipotética tribu antigua) con el significado de "la tierra de los albanos".